# how to remove some elements from an html file with notepad?

Tags: notepad++

I have a Html file containing lists, images and span tags I want to bring name of the images and text between the span tag and remove the rest , I think that there is some Reg Exp that can do this task but I can't figure out how , could you please help , this is a part from my file :

```
           <a href="text/tirette-a-cable-boite-de-vitesse-manuelle-15187" class="ga-click js--header__cat-link" data-gac="Main_menu_parts_standard" data-ga-action="15187" data-ga-label="categories" data-category-id="15187" data-parent-id="10338" data-part-type="PKW">
                        <img alt="Tirette à câble, boîte de vitesse manuelle" src="./pathback/15187.png" class="mCS_img_loaded">                                <span>Tirette à câble, boîte de vitesse manuelle</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                                        <li class="menu-category__second-item">
                    <a href="text/valve-de-commande-transmission-automatique-15185" class="ga-click js--header__cat-link" data-gac="Main_menu_parts_standard" data-ga-action="15185" data-ga-label="categories" data-category-id="15185" data-parent-id="10338" data-part-type="PKW">
                        <img alt="Valve de commande, transmission automatique" src="./pathback/15185.png" class="mCS_img_loaded">                                <span>Valve de commande, transmission automatique</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
```

I want as result to have name image + text content between span tag 
something like this :

> 15187.png+Tirette à câble, boîte de vitesse manuelle

thank you

Comment: HTML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable. A regex for such job will be terrible.

Answer (score 0):

You really should write a script that have  html parser (like [php](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)).

But if you want to do that with Notepad++, here is a way to go:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<img .*?src="[^"]+/([^/"]+).+?<span>([^<]+)</span>`
- Replace with: `$1 $2`
- *UNcheck Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<img            # literally <img and a space
.*?             # 0 or more any character but newline, not greedy
src="[^"]+/     # literally src=" followed by 1 or more non quote then a slash
([^/"]+)        # group 1, 1 or more not quote not slash
.+?             # 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
<span>          # literally <span>
([^<]+)         # group 2, 1 or more any character that is not <
</span>         # literally </span>
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1  # content of group 1, filename
    # a space
$2  # content of group 2, test inside span
```

**Result for given example:**

```
       <a href="text/tirette-a-cable-boite-de-vitesse-manuelle-15187" class="ga-click js--header__cat-link" data-gac="Main_menu_parts_standard" data-ga-action="15187" data-ga-label="categories" data-category-id="15187" data-parent-id="10338" data-part-type="PKW">
                    15187.png Tirette à câble, boîte de vitesse manuelle
                </a>
            </li>
                                    <li class="menu-category__second-item">
                <a href="text/valve-de-commande-transmission-automatique-15185" class="ga-click js--header__cat-link" data-gac="Main_menu_parts_standard" data-ga-action="15185" data-ga-label="categories" data-category-id="15185" data-parent-id="10338" data-part-type="PKW">
                    15185.png Valve de commande, transmission automatique
                </a>
            </li>
```